# In app purchase (iOS) sandbox issue. Error Domain=ASDServerErrorDomain Code=3504

Tags: swift, testing, in-app-purchase, sandbox, storekit

I get the following error message when trying to test my in-app purchase with a sandbox user.

> <SKPaymentQueue: 0x283e01090>: Payment completed with error: Error
> Domain=ASDServerErrorDomain Code=3504 "This object could not be
> found." UserInfo={storefront-country-code=SWE,
> client-environment-type=Sandbox, AMSServerErrorCode=3504,
> NSLocalizedFailureReason=This object could not be found.}

I also printed the transaction.error and go this error message:

> Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "An unknown error occurred"

I tried to search here on stack overflow and apple developer forum.

I found that others had the same issue, but no solution presented. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727800

I also made sure of the following:

1. That my in-app product identifier is the same as Im using in my app.
2. Bundle identifier for my app is the same in the development profile & app store connect.
3. The status of the in app-purchase for which Im testing on connect are set to "Ready to submit"
4. Deleted the app from my device, clean its build from xcode.
5. No documents agreement are pending on connect.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and knows how to solve it? Or has a clue on how to troubleshot it?

Comment: Did you test on a simulator?

Comment: No physical iPhone. I have previously tested the local in-app purchase with a storekit.config file, and it worked fine on a simulator. I have removed all the configuration for that now.